# Insertar registros en dos campos de dos tablas a una tabla temporal

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle-11g

Les mando saludo y agradezco de antemano por su tiempo y valiosa ayuda; mi problema surge de tres tablas en *oracle* involucradas en una relación muchos a muchos: `PLED`, `PROGRAMAS`, `DETALLE_PP_PLED` (tabla temporal).

```
TABLA PLED:         TABLA DETALLE_PP_PLED:    TABLA PROGRAMAS_PRESUPUESTARIOS:
CVE_PLED            CVE_PLED                  CVE_PP
CVE_PADRE_PLED      CVE_PP                    CVE_UNIDAD
CODIGO_PLED                                   CVE_PROGRAMA
DESCRIPCION_PLED                              ID
PAGINA_PLED                                   FECHA_REGISTRO
PARRAFO_PLED                                  HORA_REGISTRO
NIVEL_PLED                                    ACTIVO
ID                                            CVE_USUARIO
FECHA_REGISTRO                                EJERCICIO
HORA_REGISTRO
ACTIVO
CVE_USUARIO
REFERENCIA
EJERCICIO
```

La tabla `PLED` ya estaba creada en la DB; la tabla `programas` es nueva y se está poblando mediante un sistema de captura. Para que exista esta relación se debe poblar la tabla temporal con las claves primarias de las tablas involucradas; el problema que tengo es que al momento de querer insertar me genera este error:

Error que empieza en la línea: 89 del comando -

```
insert all into detalle_pp_pled (cve_pled, cve_pp) 
values((select a.cve_pled from pled a),
(select b.cve_pp from T718_PROGRAMAS_PRESUPUESTARIOS b)
Error en la línea de comandos : 91 Columna : 55
Informe de error -
Error SQL: ORA-00917: falta la coma
00917. 00000 -  "missing comma"

insert all into detalle_pp_pled (cve_pled, cve_pp) 
values((select a.cve_pled from pled a),
(select b.cve_pp from T718_PROGRAMAS_PRESUPUESTARIOS b);
```

Lo que hice es insertar primero `cve_pled` y todo de maravilla, se insertan los 755 registros pero cuando inserto `cve_pp` me inserta a partir del ultimo registro insertado en `cve_pled` y lo demás lo deja nulo

```
  cve_pled  cve_pp
    1        null
    2        null
    3        null
    .         .
    .         .
   755       null
   null       1
   null       2
```

Me estoy iniciando en este mundo y me gustaría saber si hay una forma diferente de poder hacer el llenado de la temporal. Espero me haya dado a entender, quedo al pendiente de todas sus respuestas.

Comment: Por lo pronto, pareciera que falta un paréntesis final para el `VALUE`. Y no me cierra mucho (aunque no soy muy ducho en Oracle) que se pueda insertar desde una subconsulta como lo estás haciendo. ¿Que pasa si retornan más de un valor?

Comment: así es, falta un paréntesis, fue un error de copiado, en si el resultado no cambia mucho al agregarlo, ya que me indica que hace falta la palabra clave SELECT, investigando agregue un select * from dual al final y ahora me indica en consola   ORA-01427: la subconsulta de una sola fila devuelve más de una fila, esta es la consulta insert all into detalle_pp_pled (cve_pled, cve_pp) 
values((select a.cve_pled from pled a),
(select b.cve_pp from T718_PROGRAMAS_PRESUPUESTARIOS b)) select * from dual;

Comment: El problema es que tal como escribes la consulta, el INSERT "espera" de las sentencias SQL que retorne un solo valor y no lo están haciendo. Francamente no hay forma de responderte si conocer un poco las reglas de negocio o las relaciones entre las dos tablas.

Comment: lo que busco es crear una relación muchos a muchos y así hacer la consulta necesaria, ya que esa es la idea quiero saber la forma de poder poblar  esa tabla que funge como tabla temporal pero insertando dos campos a la vez, aquí el tema es que al hacer la consulta INSERT agregando en values para cada registro un subselect me devuelve mas de un dato.